# Use PowerShell to extract string from PDF form and output to file

Tags: powershell, pdf

I have this code whereby the objective is to find all PDF files within a folder that have been modified within x days (as input by the user).

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
$title = 'PDF Last Modified'
$msg   = 'Days prior:'
$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title)
$headers = @{Expression={$_.CreationTime};Label="File Created";width=25}, `
@{Expression={$_.LastWriteTime};Label="File Edited";width=25}, `
@{Expression={"{0}" -f $_.FullName.Split("\")[-2]};Label="Folder";width=30}, `
@{Expression={$_.Name};Label="File Name";width=50}
Get-ChildItem -Path ..\ -Recurse -Filter *.pdf | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$text)} | sort LastWriteTime -descending | format-table $headers  |  out-file PDFOutput-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt -width 300
```

There are two improvements that I'd like to make.

1. Each of those PDF files is actually a form, and at the bottom of that form is a string of numbers which identify where that form needs to go. I know that I need to use itextsharp.dll to parse the PDF file; I'd like to include in the output file after "File Name" a header "Destination" and include that string from the PDF form.
2. On the initial VB-Input window, it asks how many day prior that the script should search. I'd like to add a second input that asks for any search parameters for the title, so if the user inputs, say, "receipt", the script finds any file titled *receipt*.pdf (wildcards either side of it, so it would find laptop-receipt-2015-11-17.pdf).

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much efffort in realizing your plans.

- As Get-ChildItem doesn't a provide a property `Destination` you have to add it yourself with a calculated property.
- save the gci results in a variable and iterate it to run **your** code to get the Destination on every file.
- modify the $headers hashtable to suit your needs (Label/Expression may be abbreviated)

No time to develop the crucial itextsharp.dll code for you.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\03\23\SU_1416552.ps1
$Folder = (Get-Item ..).FullName

[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$title = 'PDF Last Modified'
$msg   = 'Days prior:'
$DaysPrior = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title)

$title = 'PDF Name Part'
$msg   = 'String:'
$Namepart = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title)

$PdfFiles = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $Folder ("*{0}*" -f $NamePart)) -Recurse -File  -Filter *.pdf| 
    Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysPrior) | 
    Sort-Object  LastWriteTime -descending | 
    Select-Object -Property FullName,Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,
                            @{L='Destination';E={$Null}}

foreach ($PdfFile in $PdfFiles){
    ##
    ## Insert **your** code to get FormField Destination
    ##
    $PdfFile.Destination = "string of numbers"
}

$headers = @{L="File Created";width=25;E={$_.CreationTime}},
           @{L="File Edited" ;width=25;E={$_.LastWriteTime}},
           @{L="Folder"      ;width=30;E={$_.FullName.Split("\")[-2]}},
           @{L="File Name"   ;width=50;E={$_.Name}},
           @{L="Destination" ;width=30;E={$_.Destination}}

$PdfFiles | Format-Table $headers  |  
   Out-File PDFOutput-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt -width 300
```